# how to use C to complete a wildcard function?

Tags: c, wildcard

I am a rookie on C, and now I want to use C to complete a wildcard function. For example, I write a photo processing program named **myphoto**, and I want to use it like this: **myphoto ./photos/*.png**, and then myphoto will process all the png file in the dir one by one.

I would like to solve this problem as easily as possible, without the usage of regular expression, and I came up with a idea that maybe I could use the **EXEC** function to execute a command, but the **EXEC** function only returns int, not the char*.

So how can I solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: You need to do nothing.  The shell will expand the wildcard (globing expression) even before your program starts.

Comment: Have you tried writing that program and printing the values in argc and argv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is operating system specific. I'm giving a Posix and Linux point of view (on Windows it is different, and I don't know it).

Notice that if you are writing the program `myprog.c` compiled into `myprog` then running
`myprog photos/*.png` the `main` function in `myprog.c` is getting an array of strings (declare `int main(int argc, char**argv)` then the array of arguments has `argc` strings in array `argv` ....). The expansion is done by the shell *before* starting your `myprog` binary executable. See [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

On Linux and Posix systems: read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), you may want to use [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) and/or [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) and/or [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html). These functions are useful mostly if some data (e.g. a line in a file) contains `photos/*.jpeg` and your program want to "glob" that. You don't need to "glob" the arguments of `main`, this has been done already by your shell.

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Oh, I have just written a short program to try want you said, and now I found how powerful the shell is, thanks a lot!