# How to open a file ending with a particular extension in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a lexer using flex, and want to open and read from a file ending with a particular extension. E.g `filename.k`. I am only able to do it if I specify the file name as well as the extension.

```
FILE *myfile = fopen("a.k", "r");
        if (!myfile) {
        cout << "I can't open a.k!" << endl;
```

Can someone show me the way to open `*.k` files in C++.

I am running flex on Ubuntu. What I am trying to do is to run a flex program. The above code executes fine. I wanted a way where I can open a file with `.k` extension irrespective of the file name. Example. `./myprogram a.k` or `./myprogram b.k`. In the above example I always have to specify the file name in the code itself all the time.

Comment: See [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) and [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) libraries.

Comment: You can't.  `*.k` could refer to zero, one or many files.  How do you expect to be able to open one file given those constraints ?

Comment: "I am only able to do it if I specify the file name as well as the extension." -> The extension is part of the file name. Without the extension you don't have the full file name. Windows might hide the extension from the users, but it's still part of the file name and still required to identify the file.

Comment: @SidS by reading the containing folder

Comment: @YSC, That doesn't let you open one file with `fopen()`

Comment: @SidS It lets you list the file(s) you want to open, then do it with the appropriate tool.

Comment: @YSC, Well, Duh!  That's not what he was asking and it's platform dependent either way

Comment: @SidS No, [it is not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) anymore.

Comment: @karma: you actually have two different and unrelated questions: 1) why and when can  `fopen` fail? 2) how to get all the files matching some pattern like `*.k` ? At last, you need to mention which C++ standard you care about.

Comment: in the above example `fopen` fails when the file name is not a.k

Comment: The `#include <string>` allows you to do `if (filename.size() >= 2 && filename.substr(filename.size()-2) == ".k")` fairly easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fopen`-ing code is good, but running in conditions (e.g. in some weird [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), or without sufficient permissions) which make the `fopen` fail.

I recommend to use `errno` (perhaps implicitly thru `perror`) in that failure case to get an idea of the failure reason:

```
FILE *myfile = fopen("a.k", "r");
if (!myfile) {
     perror("fopen of a.k"); 
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

See e.g. [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html), [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (or their documentation for your particular implementation and system).

Notice that file extensions don't really exist in standard C++11 (but C++17 has [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)). On Linux and POSIX systems, file extensions are just a *convention*.

> Can someone show me the way to open *.k files in C++.

If you need to open all files with a `.k` extension, you may rely on [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) (on POSIX, run something like `yourprog *.k` in your shell, which will *expand* the `*.k` into a sequence of file names ending with `.k` before running your program, whose `main` would get an array of arguments; see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)), or you have to loop explicitly using operating system primitives or functions (perhaps with [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), ... on Linux; for Windows, read about [FindFirstFile etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx)...)

Standard C++11 don't provide a way to iterate on all files matching a given pattern. Some framework libraries ([Boost](http://boost.org/), [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/)) do provide such a way. Or you need to use operating system specific functions (e.g. to read the current [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)). But directories are not known to C++11 and are an abstraction provided by your operating system). But C++17 has [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), but you need a very recent compiler and C++ standard library to get that.

BTW, on Unix or POSIX systems, you could have one single file named `*.k`. Of course that is very poor taste and should be avoided (but you might run `touch '*.k'` in your shell to make such a file).

Regarding your edit, for Linux, I recommend running

```
./myprogram *.k
```

(then your shell will expand `*.k` into one or several arguments to `myprogram`) 
and code the `main` of your program `myprog` appropriately to iterate on arguments. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26019061/841108).

If you want to run just `myprogram` without any additional arguments, you need to code the globbing or the expansion inside it. See [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html). Or scan directories (with [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), `closedir`, [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html))

Comment: He wants to open `*.k`

Comment: @SidS: that is not mentioned in his question. What makes you think that?

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. After reading all of your answers, I realized that my question is not framed properly. I am running flex/bison in Ubuntu, I wanted to open a file with particular extension when running an object file. Such as ./myprogram a.k, I wanted a way where I can write any filename instead of a but ending with a .k extension.

Answer (score 2):

Comment to Basile's [anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286774/1312382):

> [...] Such as ./myprogram a.k, I wanted a way where I can write any filename instead of a but ending with a .k extension.

While the cited answer technically is correct, I think your true problem is how to get some arbitrary, but specific file path from the command line:

> Example: ./myprogram a.k or ./myprogram b.k

The thing is quite easy: you get the command line parameters passed directly to your main function, provided you use the variant accepting them:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

First parameter (`argv[0]`) is always the name of your programme (or an empty string, if not available), so `argc` will always be at least one. Afterwards the parameters provided follow, so invoking "./myprogram b.k" will result in argc being two and argv pointing to a char* array equivalent to the following:

```
char* argv[] =
{
    "./myprogram",
    "b.k",
    nullptr // oh, yes, the array is always null terminated...
};
```

And then, the matter gets easy: Check, if the parameter is given at all: `if(argc == 2`) or, if you are willing to accept but ignore any additional parameters, `if(argc >= 2`) or simply `if(argv[1])` (as it will be `nullptr`, if no parameter given, or the first parameter otherwise) and then use it for `fopen` or, if you prefer a more C++ like way, to open a `std::ifstream`. You might want to have additional checks, e. g. if the file name really ends with `".k"`, but that's up to you now...